Why can't I start a scan on the trading bot?
I connect to the server, but when it starts scanning, the bot closes without giving any errors.
def scan():
    global twm, conn_keys_prices, conn_keys, prices, perc, client, break_scan, loop, pump_symbol

while True:
        try:
            if exchange == 'binance':
                client = BinanceClient(api_key, api_secret)
        except Exception as e:
            sprint(f"{A}{exchange}{B}")
            print(f"Exception: {e}")
            traceback.print_exc()  
            exit_pumpbot()

        if exchange == 'binance':
            sprint(_c)
            sprint(_d)
            twm = ThreadedWebsocketManager(api_key, api_secret)
            twm.start()
            break_scan = False
            conn_keys = {}
            conn_keys_prices = {}
            prices = {}
            pump_symbol = None
            perc = None
            symbols = [line[0].lower() + '@trade' for line in tickers]
            symbols_prices = [line[0].lower() + '@kline_1m' for line in tickers]

            time.sleep(3)
            print('SCAN STARTED')
            time.sleep(1)
            print('Press ESC key to stop scan.')
            time.sleep(1)

            try:
                conn_keys[0] = twm.start_multiplex_socket(callback=process_binance_trade_message, streams=symbols)
                conn_keys_prices[0] = twm.start_multiplex_socket(callback=process_binance_kline_message, streams=symbols_prices)
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"Failed to start websocket: {e}")
                traceback.print_exc()  
                twm.stop()
                continue

            start = time.time()
            Thread(target=start_key_listener).start()
            twm.join()

            while pump_symbol is None:
                if break_scan == False:
                    time.sleep(0.001)

            twm.stop_socket(conn_keys[0])
            twm.stop_socket(conn_keys_prices[0])

I connect to the server, but when it starts scanning, the bot closes without giving any errors.

you should probably try/catch those calls and see what exceptions are thrown.  I'd suspect it's Binance refusing connection from your region.  (They are banned from certain countries)

I don't think there is any ban. I get error-free information about API connections and server status. Is it just a problem starting the scan or missing websocket connections?

you'll need to set some breakpoints I suppose.  websockets are usually for opening two-way communications where the data may come at some point in the future... so I'd expect somewhere in your code you check for the incoming data and only stop the connection afterwards.
